# python parser read_file() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'infile'

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, readfile

```
%%writefile testcipher.py
import argparse
def parse_command_line():
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("infile",type=argparse.FileType('r'),help="show this help message and exit")
    args=parser.parse_args()

def read_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path,"r") as f:
        message=f.read()
    return message
args = parse_command_line()
read_file(args.infile)

----------

%%bash

python3 testcipher.py plain_message.txt


----------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcipher.py", line 13, in <module>
    read_file(args.infile)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'infile'
```

I tried to read file with parser argument, somehow it didnt work..help please..

ignore for word requirement ignore for word requirement ignore for word requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You need return 'args' in your parse_command_line() function.

(2) Your add_argment function lead to open file directly using your argument as file name.

```
%%writefile testcipher.py

import argparse
def parse_command_line():
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("infile",type=str,help="show this help message and exit")
    args=parser.parse_args()
    return args

def read_file(file_name):
    __file = open(file_name)
    message=__file.read()
    return message

args = parse_command_line()
message = read_file(args.infile)
print (message)

----------

%%bash

python3 testcipher.py plain_message.txt


----------
```

Comment: I tried your code, it returns:TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='plain_message.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

Answer (score 0):

parse_command_line must return args object. Actually your parsing function returns None.

And of course None hasn’t any attribute whatever it’s name.